# Display the chosen value in the input field after its selecting in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, tags

If I chose from the live search drop-down let's say "Rice" (as described in the screenshot below)
[image: screenshot]

I want that the value will be displayed in the input field after I click on "Rice", how can I do that?

Here is the input tag and the a tag that I represent the values:

```
<div>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Choose food" onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} value={value} />
                    <div>
                        {result.map((result, index) => (
                            <a href='#' key={index}>
                                <div className='bg-warning'>
                                    {result}
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set state value onClick of a tag just add onClick={e => setValue(result)} to a tag

```
<div>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Choose food" onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} value={value} />
                <div>
                    {result.map((result, index) => (
                        <a href='#' key={index} onClick={e => setValue(result)}>
                            <div className='bg-warning'>
                                {result}
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Have a `onClick` on anchor tag as below and set the state, but I would choose a
  different tag (not anchor) if its not used as a link

  ```
   <a href="#" key={index} onClick={()=> setValue(result)}>
     <div className="bg-warning">{result}</div>
   </a>;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

There are some performances issues / bad practices in the code :

1. The usage of a anchor element with the href attribute set to `#` is a bad practice : it can make a undesired scroll or a undesired url change. Prefer a `div` or a `span` in this case for example.
2. The usage of a inline callback function `onClick={e => setValue(result)}` can make performances problems because at each time to component render, a new function is created, so it can re-render component & children unnecessarily. The best practice is to handle it with a outside callback function like `onClick={handleResultClick}`
3. You should use a unique id instead of an index in react *when you can*, otherwise, react cannot identify correctly the items in the list. This is even more important when you have to deal with CRUD lists

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question.